# Creating a method inside the arguments list of a java method

Tags: java, method-invocation

I came across this piece of code today :

```
client.post(getApplicationContext(),url, entity,"application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                  System.out.println(statusCode);
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                    // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
                }
            })
```

What exactly is being attempted and is it even legal ?
It does not throw any errors when compiling....

Comment: The method client.post is being passed a function body as an argument ? What does that resolve to ? What will be the lifetime of the function, as this is an asynchronous post, and the response might take a little while to receive depending on the connection. So at the time the response arrives, will the JsonHttpResponseHandler(), as defined here, be alive to process it ?

Comment: That's an anonymous class.

Comment: No it is not a function body. An object is passed. And that object exists as long as the `post()` method keeps the reference to it!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose method parameter accepts object wich extends JsonHttpResponseHandler object. And here is passing such new object generated pragrammatically as anonymous class. So it is legal in java.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#syntax-of-anonymous-classes